# Under what scenarios, react lifecycle hooks is a must

Tags: reactjs

The following is the official case of the react life cycle hook. In the following case, if I make a slight change, change setInterval to setTimeout and put it in render(), so that setTimeout will setState, and then loop call render(), loop setTimeout. It can also be achieved , So why is it necessary to use life cycle hooks in this case, or what are the benefits? To clean the code? In order to reduce memory consumption? ?

Official example:

```
 
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
  this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    }), 1000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My modification

```
 
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }
 
  render() {
    this.timerID = setTimeout(
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    }),1000);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from 知名喷子
Reference: https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000040633806

The title does not match the question: the title asks about the general situation, and the question describes a special situation.
Let me talk about the title first, what scenarios are react lifecycle hooks necessary? There are at least two scenarios:

1.Methods that only need to be executed or must be executed once in the entire life cycle, such as rendering Baidu map to a canvas in the component, because Baidu map initialization is relatively expensive and has its own state, so it is initialized multiple times It is definitely not wise, then it is more appropriate to register a componentDidMount to initialize;

2.You need to rely on a certain process in the life cycle to get the information, or take Baidu map as an example. If you need to modify the state of the map by the parent component parameter, then you should register componentWillReceiveProps or getDerivedStateFromProps to monitor the latest modification of the parent component parameter. Although you can get the parameters in the place, you will not listen to the parameter changes.

Obviously, the official website example conforms to the first situation above. The code for registering the timer only needs to be executed once, and the timer should be cancelled later, and the cancelled code only needs to be executed once.

Let's talk about your implementation method, it can also be used, but the application area is very narrow. If this timer is not used for timing, but for polling, if the polling result is the same as the last time, it will not be re-rendered, and the next delayer cannot be automatically registered. Then you can only use other methods to do so. It is an unnecessary performance waste to trigger a non-rendering once.

Another point, React always emphasizes that the render function should be a pure function, that is, given the same parameters should get the same result, and the delayer actually has the so-called "side effects".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, uou can putting setTimeout in the render method. But when component re-render, new `interval` will be created and we have a lot of interval. You can try like this.

We must put in `componentDidMount` to make sure it only create one time. We also use `this.timerID` to clear interval when component is unmounted. If we don't clear. the interval still run when component is unmounted

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a function (in this case, the interval) in the `render()` function, this will be created in each component render, so it's really bad performance wise, (`render` method will happen in less than 1 second).

`componentDidMount` is good for subscription or do something after a component is mounted, as well as `componentWillUnmount` is good for unsubscribe.

So when you use intervals you want to initialize it in `componentDidMount` and clear it in `componentWillUnmount`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```

Comment: Hi Menuel, even we use ComponentDidMount, render would be called every sec as setInterval update state every sec. I know the correct answer. What confused me would be why we prefer ComponentDidMount over using setTimeout in render(). Just simply because more memory cosumed if creating setTimeout() each render ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from 李十三, reference:https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000040633806

In this way, if there are other state updates, there will be multiple timeout timers. Even if you clear before the set, other renderings will re-trigger the render to cause the previous one to be cleared. So your solution is poor and pointless. An example without an application scenario to defeat an official example/common solution

But just from your example, if the entire program has only this component, the entire component has only one state, and nothing else affects the situation, it’s okay. It’s safer to clear it before setTimeout.